# Apostol, Vol I Ch. 14: When defining an arc length function $s(t)=\Lambda(a,t)$ why is it necessary to specify $s(a)=0$?

Tags: calculus, arc-length

In Apostol's *Calculus*, Ch. 14 "Vector-Valued Functions" section 14.12, he derives the result that the function representing the arc length of a parametric curve is given by the integral of speed along the curve.

I have a very specific question about one single step in the derivation, the outline of which is as follows

We have a curve $\vec{r}(t)$, $t\in [a,b]$ and $\vec{r}$ is continuous on this interval.

We create a partition of $[a,b]$, $P=\{a=t_0,...,t_n=b\}$ and obtain a polygon with vertices at the points $\vec{r}(t_0),...\vec{r}(t_n)$. This polygon has length $\lvert \pi(P)\rvert  =\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lVert \vec{r}(t_i)-\vec{r}(t_{i-1}) \rVert$

If $\vert \pi(P)\rvert$ has an upper bound then it means the curve is rectifiable. It also means there is a least upper bound which is defined as the arc length between $a$ and $b$, denoted $\Lambda(a,b)$.

By definition, then, $\lvert \pi(P)\rvert \leq \Lambda(a,b) \leq M$ where $M$ is any upper bound for $\lvert \pi(P)\rvert$.

**Now for my question**

At this point, Apostol defines an arc length function $s$, defined as follows

$$s(t)=\Lambda(a,t)\ \text{if}\ t>a\ \ \ \ \ s(a)=0$$

He says

> The statement $s(a)=0$ simply means we are assuming the motion begins
> when $t=a$.

Why did he have to say $s(a)=0$?

I'm not sure if $\Lambda (a,a)$ is defined. If it isn't, then defining it is an assumption, but why does this specify the start of the motion (can a motion not start at some negative $t$?)?

Comment: At time $t=0$ no distance has been travelled; thus the length from the initial point $\mathbf{r}(0)$ to $\mathbf{r}(0)$ is $0$.

Comment: Sure, but the way he wrote it is sorta weird right. The motion doesn't have to begin at $t=0$ right?

Comment: There is no problem if you start your clock at $t=a$. The idea is somewhat similar to $F(x)=\int^x_a f$ in that  $F(a)=0$.